# How to properly preserve image dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, python-imaging-library

i am currently working on the project where i have to train a network to reconstruct corrupted images from input. Each input image is different in size and has cropped out part in it, which my network should 'restore'.

So i trained the autoencoder, time for test restoration. I load each test image into model and save the output:

```
to_tensor = transforms.ToTensor()
new_test = []

for i in test_data['images']:
    i = to_tensor(i)
    new_test.append(i)

test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=new_test, batch_size=1)

def reconstruct(net, loader):
    for i,data in enumerate(loader):
        data = data.to(device)
        output = net(data)
        #save_image(data, f'test_outs/damaged_input_{i}.jpg')
        save_image(output, f'test_outs/recon_output_{i}.jpg')

net.to(device)
reconstruct(net, test_loader)
```

These reconstructions are then used to crop out the restored part:

```
from glob import glob
from pathlib import Path

def cropper(image_array, crop_size, crop_center):
    if type(image_array) != np.ndarray:
        raise ValueError('not a numpy array')
    if type(crop_size) != tuple or type(crop_center) != tuple:
        raise ValueError('use tuple as input for crop_size and crop_center')
    if len(crop_size) != 2 or len(crop_center) != 2:
        raise ValueError('invalid amount of values')
    if crop_size[0] % 2 == 0 or crop_size[1] % 2 == 0:
        raise ValueError('crop_size values should be odd!')

    img = image_array.copy()
    crop_array = np.zeros_like(image_array)

    size_x =  round(crop_center[0] - (crop_size[0]-1)/2)
    center_x = round(crop_center[0] + (crop_size[0]+1)/2)
    size_y = round(crop_center[1] - (crop_size[1]-1)/2)
    center_y = round(crop_center[1] + (crop_size[1]+1)/2)

    border_right = size_y
    border_left = size_x
    border_up = image_array.shape[0] - center_y
    border_down = image_array.shape[1] - center_x

    if border_right < 20 or border_left < 20:
        raise ValueError('minimal distance between crop and border is less than 20')
    if border_up < 20 or border_down < 20:
        raise ValueError('minimal distance between crop and border is less than 20')

    target_array = image_array[int(size_x):int(center_x), int(size_y):int(center_y)]
    pad = np.negative(target_array)
    ones_pad = np.ones_like(target_array)
    img[int(size_x):int(center_x), int(size_y):int(center_y)] += pad
    crop_array[int(size_x):int(center_x), int(size_y):int(center_y)] += ones_pad
    image_array = img

    return (image_array, crop_array, target_array)

def rgb2gray(rgb_array: np.ndarray, r=0.2989, g=0.5870, b=0.1140):
    grayscale_array = (rgb_array[..., 0] * r +
                       rgb_array[..., 1] * g +
                       rgb_array[..., 2] * b)
    grayscale_array = np.round(grayscale_array)
    grayscale_array = np.asarray(grayscale_array, dtype=np.uint8)
    return grayscale_array

def load_recons(root = 'test_outs'):
    recons = []
    path = Path(root).glob('**/*.jpg')
    for enum, f in enumerate(path):
        img = Image.open(f)
        arr = np.asarray(img)
        arr = rgb2gray(arr)
        recons.append(arr)
    return recons

recs = load_recons()

def crop_tests(recons, crop_centrs = test_data['crop_centers'], crop_szs = test_data['crop_sizes']):
    for enum, (i,j,arr) in enumerate(zip(crop_centrs, crop_szs, recons)):
            image, crop, target = cropper(arr, j, i)
            Image.fromarray(target).save(f'test_final/{enum}_target.jpg')

crop_tests(recs)
```

But the problem is when i call `crop_tests`, i get one of the exceptions:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-27-f927403b1f35> in <module>
      6             Image.fromarray(target).save(f'test_final/{enum}_target.jpg')
      7 
----> 8 crop_tests(recs)
      9 

<ipython-input-27-f927403b1f35> in crop_tests(recons, crop_centrs, crop_szs)
      3 def crop_tests(recons, crop_centrs = test_data['crop_centers'], crop_szs = test_data['crop_sizes']):
      4     for enum, (i,j,arr) in enumerate(zip(crop_centrs, crop_szs, recons)):
----> 5             image, crop, target = cropper(arr, j, i)
      6             Image.fromarray(target).save(f'test_final/{enum}_target.jpg')
      7 

~\proj_git\folder_preparator.py in cropper(image_array, crop_size, crop_center)
     52                 raise ValueError('minimal distance between crop and border is less than 20')
     53         if border_up < 20 or border_down < 20:
---> 54                 raise ValueError('minimal distance between crop and border is less than 20')
     55 
     56 

ValueError: minimal distance between crop and border is less than 20
```

This means, that the square to crop out is very near the border of reconstructed image (less than 20 pixels). However, it was not a problem with damaged image.

So the shapes of reconstructed images are following:

```
(70, 93)
(70, 93)
(70, 93)
(70, 93)
(70, 93)
(93, 70)
(70, 93)
(93, 70)
(93, 70)
(70, 93)
(93, 70)
(70, 93)
(70, 93)
(70, 93)
(70, 93)
```

However, shapes of original images are in a bit different order:

```
(70, 93)
(70, 93)
(70, 93)
(70, 93)
(70, 93)
(70, 93)
(70, 93)
(70, 93)
(93, 70)
(93, 70)
(70, 93)
(70, 93)
(70, 93)
(100, 70)
```

So i need my reconstructions to be of exactly same shape as the input, but i can't see the problem in the code myself. Could you please help me find it out? Feel free to ask additional questions.